# nodejs, jade escape markup

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have an Express app using the default Jade view engine. When I try to render HTML as-is in a `<pre>` element, it gets rendered as actual DOM elements instead of literal characters.

```
h1 Code Sample
pre
  code
    <div>some text</div>
```

Output:

```
<h1>Code Sample</h1>
<pre>
  <code>
    <div>some text</div>
  </code>
</pre>
```

How do I escape the HTML so that it gets rendered as follows?

```
<h1>Code Sample</h1>
<pre>
  <code>
    &lt;div&gt;some text&lt;/div&gt;
  </code>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 23):

Jade uses the bang to force unescaped output. So you turn regular output to unescaped output with the following construct: `!=`
If your content is inside an div tag you could do the following:

```
div!= content
```

Comment: The post is asking how to **escape** html, not unescape. See my answer below.

Answer (score 19):

As an addition, here is another use case which you need to consider:

If you are extrapolating the HTML content using the `#{...}`, it will still give the wrong output.
For that use case, you need the `!{...}` alternative.

So,

```
div= varname
```

becomes

```
div!= varname
```

---

And

```
div #{varname} is extrapolated badly
```

becomes

```
div !{varname} is extrapolated perfectly
```

Answer (score 8):

Actually the OP asks for the escaping, not the unescaping. Which I ran into today.

Let assume, that you have `varName` variable with `<b>FooBar</b>` content.

Then this template will use the escaped value:

```
#foobar= varName
```

so it becomes:

```
<div id="foobar">&lt;b&gt;FooBar&lt;/b&gt;</div>
```

If you use the bang operator:

```
#foobar!= varName
```

jade won't escape it, so it becomes:

```
<div id="foobar"><b>FooBar</b></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the official way:

```
code= '<div>This code is' + ' <escaped>!</div>'
<code>&lt;div&gt;This code is &lt;escaped&gt;!&lt;/div&gt;</code>
```

http://jade-lang.com/reference/#unescapedbufferedcode

Comment: KISS ftw. Not sure if the author thought this was possible, but it's the best solution here.

Answer (score 2):

It's not built in to Jade, but you can do it with a **filter**:
(This can be added anywhere at the top of app.js.)

```
require('jade').filters.escape = function( block ) {
  return block
    .replace( /&/g, '&amp;'  )
    .replace( /</g, '&lt;'   )
    .replace( />/g, '&gt;'   )
    .replace( /"/g, '&quot;' )
    .replace( /#/g, '&#35;'  )
    .replace( /\\/g, '\\\\'  )
    .replace( /\n/g, '\\n'   );
}
```

Then use the 'escape' filter in your jade file:

```
h1 Code Sample
pre
  code
    :escape
      <div>some text</div>
```

Output:

```
<h1>Code Sample</h1>
<pre>
  <code>&lt;div&gt;hi&lt;/div&gt;</code>
</pre>
```

Source: [Embedding escaped code in a Jade template](http://www.paulzumbrun.com/posts/jade-and-google-code-prettify/)