# How to insert variable from angularJS to string in jade template (node.js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

If I have some value from angular  `$scope.id = '123'`, how can I use it in my jade template in node.js? I'd like to use it as part of the link.

```
p
   | {{id}} // It does work...

form(name="Remove", action="/cam/{{id}}_method=DELETE", method="post")
// ...but it doesn't
      button(type='submit')
           | ready
```

Answer (score 2):

When using Jade you can use `!=` operator for unescape HTML encoding.

```
form(name="Remove", action!="/cam/{{id}}_method=DELETE", method="post")
```

However this might lead to interpolation problems. Therefore, I would suggest you to have a function in a controller like so

```
$scope.form_url = function (id) {
  return '/cam/' + id + '_method=DELETE';
};
```

then this should do the trick:

```
form(name="Remove", action="{{form_url()}}", method="post")
```

Check these sources: 
[nodejs, jade escape markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926247/nodejs-jade-escape-markup),
[AngularJS multiple expressions concatenating in interpolation with a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405162/angularjs-multiple-expressions-concatenating-in-interpolation-with-a-url)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
form(name="Remove", action="'/cam/' + {{id}} + '_method=DELETE'", method="post")
```

Answer (score 0):

Jade uses {} as an eval indicator when not prefixed by a pipe, so you'll need to use angular bindings that don't need this prefix. For your example I would create a controller function and pass it the ID and method. Here's an example:

```
script.
    angular.module('formapp', [])
        .controller('formctrl', function($scope, $http){
            $scope.formsubmit = function(id, method){
                $http({
                    method: method,
                    url: '/cam/' + id + '_method=DELETE'
                });
            };
        })
form(ng-controller="formctrl" name="Remove", ng-submit="formsubmit(id, 'post')")
  button(type='submit')
       | ready
```

Comment: You sure? I have set a breakpoint, and debugger never reached him.